# Existence of a countably infinite set in weakened versions of $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Tags: set-theory, axioms

The [axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) promises us an inductive set that contains $\varnothing$, but does not promise us a *countable* inductive set.

**I'm wondering how much you can weaken the ability of some of the other axioms to create new sets out of uncountable sets (choice, separation, replacement, union) without losing the provability of the existence of a countably infinite set.**

---

For the purposes of this question, the weakened version of the axiom of choice is the [axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice).

For separation and replacement, I impose the additional constraint that the parameter $A$ in the statements of the axioms below must be a countable set, giving countable separation and countable replacement, respectively.

Here is the ordinary axiom schema of specification; the axiom schema of countable specification imposes the additional constraint that $A$ is countable.

$$ \exists B \mathop. (\forall x \mathop. x \in B \leftrightarrow x \in A \land \varphi(\cdots, A)) $$

Likewise for replacement

$$ \exists B \forall x \in A \mathop. (\exists y \mathop. \varphi(\cdots, x, y) \to \exists z \in B \mathop. \varphi(\cdots, x, z)) $$

For union, I define countable union as the axiom that allows unary unions of countable sets only.

$$ \exists B \mathop. \forall c \mathop. (c \in B \leftrightarrow (\exists D \mathop. c \in D \land D \in A)) \; \text{is the axiom of union} $$

$$ \text{$A$ is countable} \to \exists B \mathop. \forall c \mathop. (c \in B \leftrightarrow (\exists D \mathop. c \in D \land D \in A)) \; \text{is the axiom of countable union} $$

I don't think that the remaining axioms, pairing, extensionality, powerset, and regularity  will help make countably infinite sets out of uncountable ones.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can just apply separation (without any parameters at all) to any inductive set $I$ using the formula "is an ordinal not containing any nonzero limit ordinal."

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, by "the parameter" I meant the "original set" that we're invoking separation or replacement "on". I'll include explicit statements of the axioms and make that more clear. What is the original set usually called?

Comment: How do you define "countable" in this context?

Comment: @NoahSchweber That's a good question. I was wondering how that worked for countable choice. Can I talk about sets that are in bijection with the intersection of all inductive sets but without committing to the existence of the intersection of all inductive sets?

Comment: Given that you're wondering whether any set can be proved to be countable, I don't know why you're even bothering to "weaken" these axioms to only apply to countable sets.  Why not just remove them entirely? (Or restrict them to apply only to finite sets?)

Comment: I'm not wondering whether sets can be proven to be countable per se, I'm wondering at what point I cross over a threshold and need to insist on the existence of a countable infinite set as an axiom. I'm interested in set theories that can be shown to be weaker than ZFC as usually presented using reasoning that's fairly shallow (e.g. countable choice is a restriction of ordinary choice).

Comment: Given any infinite set $X$,  the second power set of $X$ contains a countably infinite set. Namely, $X_n$ is the set of subsets of $X$ with exactly $n$ elements.